# How can I prove that the sequence $a_n := x^n$ with $0 \leq x < 1$ tends to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Basically the title. I want to prove that the sequence $a_n := x^n$ with $0 \leq x < 1$ tends to $0$. Conceptually, this is clear to me but I struggle with finding a formal proof.

**Edit**:
To rephrase this a bit, how can I prove that it is a positive decreasing sequence and that $0$ is its limit?

Comment: Hint$$n>\frac{\log\epsilon}{\log x}\implies x^n<\epsilon$$

Comment: Alt. hint: it's a positive decreasing sequence, so it has a limit, then you can pass $a_{n+1} = x a_n$ to the limit.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I think it's a little bit uneccessary to use $log$ here. This can be proved only by the binomial theorem and Archimedean property.

Comment: Since you'll probably need to construct the exp function first, and/or prove IVT first in order to prove properties for log.

Comment: @dxiv really like this hint. extremely simple

Comment: @dxiv This sounds like a good approach, could you tell me a bit more on how to do this?

Comment: @Max Posted as an answer since it became too long for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$ the sequence $a_n$ is identically $0$ so there is nothing left to prove. Otherwise, to formalize the hint posted in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129044/how-can-i-prove-that-the-sequence-a-n-xn-with-0-leq-x-1-tends-to-0#comment8540567_4129044) when $x \in (0, 1)$, it is enough to note the following.

- $a_n$ is a sequence of positive numbers, so it is bounded below by $0$.
- $a_n$ is decreasing since $0 \lt x \lt 1 \implies a_{n+1} = x^{n+1} = x \cdot x^n \lt x^n = a_n$.
- A decreasing sequence bounded below is convergent by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), so $a_n$ converges to a limit no smaller than the lower bound $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L \ge 0$.
- Any subsequence of a convergent sequence [converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties) itself to the same limit, in particular $b_n = a_{n+1}$ converges to the same limit $L$.
- Both sides of $a_{n+1} = x \cdot a_n$ are convergent, so the equality can be "*passed to the limit*" i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = x \cdot \lim_{n \to\infty} a_n$, or $L = x \cdot L$. Since  $x \ne 1$ it follows that $L = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x = 1/k$ for some $k>1$. It's same to prove that $a_n = k^n$ can be arbitrarily big for all $n \geq N$.

Let $k = 1+y$ where $y > 0$. Then $k^n = (1+y)^n = 1+ny + ... > 1+ny$. The rest is easy to prove by the Archimedean property.